# NestedScrollView with recycler set scroll position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a **NestedScrollView** with a **RecyclerView** inside.

Each item within the RecyclerView has an **EditText**.

If the user LongClicks an **EditText** I want the screen to scroll such that the position of the editetext within the recyclerview scrolls to the top of the screen....

tried a lot of methods but think the nestedscrollview combined with recycler might be hindering this...

The reason i want this behaviour is that suppose an item in the recyclerview is near the bottom of the screen, if i click this the keyboard enters and it will be hidden, hence i want it to shift to the top, that way the edittext is visible